# Mysql: Why I can't to add a field to a database?

Tags: mysql

I add to a record to a database, but a fieldname "name" don't to add to the my table.

```
id  bigint(80) unsigned NO  PRI     auto_increment
name    varchar(80) YES UNI

INSERT INTO user (`id`, `name`)VALUES ('1', 'user1');

SELECT * FROM .user;
```

result:
**id**     "1"
**name**    "null"

Comment: what is the error that you are facing?

Comment: remove single quotes from ('id','name') and try again

Comment: @SagarPawar these around `id` and `name` are backticks and they are good in there, on the other hand `'1'` is better as just `1`

Answer (score 0):

can you just try with this statement also and see if it resolves the issue

INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ('uuser1');